# Trigger an event when textbox contains specific keycode

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am currently working on a jQuery functionality to check a textbox for certain  character values and then trigger some event depending on what character it is.

I figured the easiest way to process this would be by checking on keycodes. I have tried some different things to make the event trigger, but nothing seems to happen.

One of the things I want to check is if a textbox contains an `@` character (which is not allowed in the specific textbox, and it's keycode is 64 according to this site - [expandinghead](http://www.expandinghead.net/keycode.html))

Some of the code I've attempted to use:

```
$("#NoEmailAllowed").live({
    "keyup": function(e) { 
         if((e.keyCode == 64) || (e.which == 64))
         { 
            $(this).addClass("redBg");
         }
     }
});

$("#NoEmailAllowed:contains('@')").live({
     "keyup": function() { 
        $(this).addClass("redBg");
     }
});

$("#NoEmailAllowed").keyup(function(){
     if(this.val().contains("@"))
     {
        $(this).addClass("redBg");
     }
});
```

I've tried a lot of others too, but they were quiet similar to the ones above.

So just to make everything clear about what I'm trying to achieve is:
When a user enters something in this textbox the jquery shall check for any `@` characters on-the-fly, and if it finds any `@` characters, trigger an event - for instance an alert or add a css class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `keyup()` event operates with scancodes, you're better off using `keypress()` to catch actual text entry (as mentioned in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)):

```
$(function(){
    $('#NoEmailAllowed').keypress(function(e) { 
        if(e.which == 64)
        { 
           $(this).addClass("redBg");
        }
    });
});
```

jQuery normalizes `e.which`, there is no need to check anything else.